# glimpse(sql tab) is not working for nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, nopcommerce, glimpse

In Nopcommerce, I have added nuget package Install-Package Glimpse.MVC5 it's working fine for mvc,

when I add Install-Package Glimpse.EF6 & ADO it's throwing like

> Unable to define EFProfiledDbProviderServices class of type
>   'GlimpseDbProviderServices'. Please check that your web.config defines
>   a  section underneath .
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: Unable to define
>   EFProfiledDbProviderServices class of type
>   'GlimpseDbProviderServices'. Please check that your web.config defines
>   a  section underneath .

[image]
I think this error is coming because of nopcommerce database is generating dynamically.But I was not able get any solution for this issue.

Please help me out of this

Comment: Check `settings.txt` for correct connection string.

Comment: settings.txt has connection string and dataprovider. What I need to change in settings.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing minifier tool from my project, Actually minifier is overriding GlimpseDbProviderServices.